# PHP - mkdir : Create a folder with the same rights as it's parent

Tags: php, permissions, chmod, mkdir

Is there a way in PHP to create a **`folder`** with the same permission as it's **`parent`**.

For example:
I have a folder `/a/b` with `0755` permissions,
I want to create the folder `a/b/c` with the same permissions. `0755` in this case.

As far as i know, PHP creates folders with `0777` permission by default with the `mkdir` function. Is there a smart way to detect the parent folder permission an then create that child folder with the same chmod?

Edit: Here I am looking for a solution to create a floder with `mkdir` not how to retrieve a file/folder permissions.

@ArtisticPhoenix solution is what i looked for.

Thank you.

Comment: `chmod()` is what you are looking for https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php  AND `fileperms()` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fileperms.php

Comment: I think you can just do `chmod($filename, fileperms($parent))`  You may have to use `substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms($parent)),-4)`  (from the documentation page) to turn it into just the Octet, but I never used it in chmod before.  For `$parent` don't forget about `dirname($filename)`

Comment: @miken32 thank you for your response. but no it's not a duplicate, actually the solution is the sum of the two suggestions. ArtisticPhoenix has done it in his solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this thing I just wiped up (untested)

```
chmod($filename, substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms(dirname($filename))),-4));
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fileperms.php

I think the other functions are pretty self explanatory, or basic enough they don't warrant a link. `dirname($filename)` of course being the files directory.

This `substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms(...)),-4)` stuff comes from the documentation page:

> **Example #1** Display permissions as an octal value
>
> ```
>   echo substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms('/tmp')), -4);
>   echo substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms('/etc/passwd')), -4);
> ```

Which seems like something we would want to use, because that is what `chmod` wants, but it may be worth testing if that is required or not (maybe it's smart enough to understand it). I haven't really used `fileperms` before.  In most cases `is_writable` is all I've needed.

Hope it works.